# Looking for a free macOS PostgreSQL client with AWS IAM authentication, OR can script the password field

Tags: macos, postgresql

pgAdmin4 can do this with the advanced "Password exec cmd" field, it basically automates the process described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-iam-authentication-to-connect-with-pgadmin-amazon-aurora-postgresql-or-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/). I just don't like pgAdmin4 so far.

I understand DBeaver has native AWS IAM authentication, but not in the free version.

Are there any alternatives that you would recommend?